# How i can export/import groups from WhatsApp?

Tags: android, android-contacts, whatsapp

How can i get contact list from some group from whatsApp, or how i can create group in WhatsApp with contacts from my app? I didn't see an public API for this purposes but app like [Drupe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.drupe.app&hl=uk) has such functionality. How it could be implemented?

Comment: Like you rightly mentioned, WhatApp doesn't have any public API for Android. There were some 3rd party APIs that did integrate Whatsapp, but all were found to be in violation of WhatsApp Terms and Conditions. Several apps back-compiled a WhatsApp versions (I know that version 1.0.3 was decompiled due to low obfuscation), but that is also illegal.

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal but how Drupe can do this without api and access to whatsApp db?

Comment: As I said, several versions were de-compiled. I believe they use back-compiled code. Maybe code-injection. In a nutshell, IMHO, they are not doing anything thats legal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the information from Whatsapp [CHECK](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)  But does not exist an API.